# How to update column in table from two different tables USING DML Command

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, dml

I have three different tables here:

`df_umts_relation` table:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      cell_name      |     n_cell_name  |    technology       |   source_ops_num |   target_ops_num |     
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       121           |       221        |         UMTS        |         1        |                  |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       122           |       222        |         GSM         |         2        |                  |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       123           |       223        |         UMTS        |         3        |                  |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       124           |       224        |         GSM         |         4        |                  |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       125           |       225        |         GSM         |         5        |                  |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       126           |       226        |         UMTS        |         6        |                  |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       127           |       227        |         UMTS        |         7        |                  |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

So now I want to update `target_ops_num` from the two below tables

`df_umts_carrier` table as this table contains those thow columns I want to work on them and contains some integer values also:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      opsnum_umts    |  cell_name_umts  |     
|---------------------|------------------|
```

as I have another table called `df_gsm_carrier`:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      opsnum_gsm     |  cellname        |     
|---------------------|------------------|
```

So All I need I want to update `[MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation].[target_ops_num]` CASE WHEN `technology`is `UMTS` then update from table `df_umts_carrier` ELSE `technology` is `GSM` then update from `df_gsm_carrier` on `n_cell_name` = `cell_name_umts` and on `n_cell_name` =  `cellname`

So I tried to create a query as the below one works with one condition only and it's update the the rows which is `UMTS` only:

```
UPDATE [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation]
SET [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation].[target_ops_num] = [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_carrier].[opsnum_umts]
FROM [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation]
INNER JOIN [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_carrier]
ON [n_cell_name] = [cell_name_umts]
```

and works fine but doesn't update the rows which contains `GSM`...

On other way I tried to create a query to handle this but it didn't update the `GSM` part and take a long of time:

```
UPDATE [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation]
SET [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation].[target_ops_num] = (CASE WHEN [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation].[technology] = 'UMTS' 
THEN [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_carrier].[opsnum_umts] ELSE [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_gsm_carrier].[opsnum_gsm] END)
FROM [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation]
LEFT JOIN [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_carrier]
ON [n_cell_name] = [cell_name_umts]
LEFT JOIN [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_gsm_carrier]
ON [n_cell_name] = [cell_name]
```

So any one have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please add database tag. Thanks!

Comment: @VBoka Edited thanks you for your interests :)

Comment: You are fast, that is nice. But what I wanted is : Oracle, MySQL, Postgresql, SQLServer....One of this

Comment: @VBoka updated it's sql-server express :)

Comment: Is there any date in df_umts_carrier  and in df_gsm_carrier ? Please update one or two values to see ? Thanks!

Comment: @VBoka no there's no date in the tables

Comment: But you want to update your df_umts_relation  table "So All I need I want to update [MyNewDatabase].[dbo].[df_umts_relation].[target_ops_num]" with the data from the df_umts_carrier  and df_gsm_carrier tables and there is no data in this two tables ?

Comment: @VBoka no there's data in those other tables an integer data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208547/discussion-between-vboka-and-mahmoud-al-haroon).

Comment: Please update your question with this data. Two rows will be enough for each table.

Comment: @VBoka you mean change the title to `Two rows will be enough for each table`

Comment: Hi @MahmoudAl-Haroon Please join me in the chat. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208547/discussion-between-vboka-and-mahmoud-al-haroon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this will help.

```
update df_umts_relation
set target_ops_num = ( select case when dur.technology = 'UMTS' then du.cell_name_umts
                                   when dur.technology = 'GSM' then dg.cellname
                              end
from df_umts_relation dur
left join df_umts_carrier du on  dur.n_cell_name = du.opsnum_umts
left join df_gsm_carrier dg on dur.n_cell_name = dg.opsnum_umts
where dur.id= df_umts_relation.id)
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5e6349cbbcca1af3c4e78cbf6afbc465)